# Testing js promises with Mocha, Chai, chaiAsPromised and Sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test a function that reads in a file and returns a promise with the file's contents.

```
function fileContents(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
      if (err) { reject(err); }
      else { resolve(data); }
    });
  });
}
```

The unit test for the above

```
describe('Testing fileContents', function () {

afterEach(function () {
    fs.readFile.restore();
});

it('should return the contents of the fallBack file', function () {
    let fileContents = '<div class="some-class">some text</div>';

    sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile').returns(function(path, callback) {
        callback(null, fileContents);
    });

    let fileContentsPromise = fileContents();

    return fileContentsPromise
      .then(data => {
        expect(data).to.eventually.equal(fileContents);
      });

 });
```

The above test errs with

```
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I also tried

```
describe('Testing fileContents', function () {

  afterEach(function () {
    fs.readFile.restore();
  });

  it('should return the contents of the fallBack file', function (done) {
    let fileContents = '<div class="some-class">some text</div>';

    sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile').returns(function(path, callback) {
        callback(null, fileContents);
    });

    let fileContentsPromise = fileContents();

  fileContentsPromise.then(function(data){
    expect(data).to.equal(fileContents);
    done();
  });
});
```

and got the same error. The function is working in my local site, but I don't know how to write a test for it. I'm new to js. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code. For instance, you redeclare `fileContents` in your test and assign it a string value, which of course won't work with doing `fileContents()` in the same test. I'm going to concentrate on two conceptual problems rather than the "duh"-type mistakes like this one.

The two conceptual problems are:

1. To have `fs.readFile` call your callback with fake values you must use `.yields`. Using `.returns` changes the return value, which you do not use. So stub it like this:

   ```
   sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile').yields(null, fakeContents);
   ```
2. You are using the `.eventually` functionality provided by `chai-as-promised` on a non-promise, but you have to use it on a promise for it to work properly so your test should be:

   ```
   return expect(fileContentsPromise).to.eventually.equal(fakeContents);
   ```

Here's code that works:

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const fs = require("fs");
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const expect = chai.expect;

// We need to have filename defined somewhere...
const filename = "foo"; 
function fileContents(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
      if (err) { reject(err); }
      else { resolve(data); }
    });
  });
}

describe('Testing fileContents', function () {

    afterEach(function () {
        fs.readFile.restore();
    });

    it('should return the contents of the fallBack file', function () {
        let fakeContents = '<div class="some-class">some text</div>';

        sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile').yields(null, fakeContents);

        let fileContentsPromise = fileContents();

        return expect(fileContentsPromise).to.eventually.equal(fakeContents);
    });
});
```

Comment: yields is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. Apologies for the red herring with the variable names, which are not in my original code; I had changed the code to be more generic and didn't notice that I had used the same name for the 'fake content' and the function name. Anyway, thanks again!